# WPF Scrollviewer resets offset

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, scrollviewer

I have some editors inside a `StackPanel`, this `StackPanel` is wrapped insde a `ScrollViewer`. The scrolling works fine, and the `height`of the `ScrollViewer` is set dynamically based on the height of the window.
The problem is, that the `ScrollViewer` resets the `VerticalOffset` if one of the `RadioButtons` is clicked or if the user selects all text in one of the `TextBoxes`, as there is no wrapping and the text overflows the width of the `TextBox`.

All the content inside the `StackPanel` is created dynamically. This is the generated XAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Name="LeftEditorStack">
        <StackPanel Name="OuterPanelFirstname">
            <RadioButton Name="FirstnameEnabled"></RadioButton>
            <TextBox></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <!--And many more editors to come-->
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And this is the basic view of the generated XAML code. This is one of three columns, the columns look all like this.

[image: UI]

How can I prevent this behaviour?

**Edit:**
Here is the code that generates my controls inside a for loop:

```
editorAttribute = (EditorAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(properties[i], typeof(Weiss.WPF.Controls.Classes.EditorAttribute));
isEnabledAttribute = (IsEnabledAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(properties[i], typeof(Weiss.WPF.Controls.Classes.IsEnabledAttribute));
displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(properties[i], typeof(DisplayAttribute));

stackUId = Regex.Replace(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", String.Empty), @"[\d-]", String.Empty);

outerPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical, DataContext = this, Name = String.Format("OuterPanel{0}{1}", displayAttribute.GroupName, stackUId) };

radioGroup = new RadioButton() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, GroupName = displayAttribute.GroupName, Name = String.Format("{0}Enabled{1}", displayAttribute.GroupName, stackUId), Content = displayAttribute.Name };
radioGroup.Checked += radioGroup_Checked;

editorBinding = new Binding();
editorBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(String.Format("DataContext.{0}", isEnabledAttribute.ElementName));

editorBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType = typeof(StackPanel), AncestorLevel = 2 };
radioGroup.SetBinding(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, editorBinding);

if (this.GetType().GetProperty(String.Format("{0}Enabled", displayAttribute.GroupName)) != null)
{
    radioGroup.IsChecked = this.GetType().GetProperty(isEnabledAttribute.ElementName).GetValue(this, null) is Boolean &&
                           (Boolean)this.GetType().GetProperty(isEnabledAttribute.ElementName).GetValue(this, null);
}

outerPanel.Children.Add(radioGroup);

editor = Activator.CreateInstance(editorAttribute.EditorType) as FrameworkElement;
editor.IsEnabled = false;
editorBinding = new Binding();
editorBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(String.Format("DataContext.{0}", properties[i].Name));
editorBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType = typeof(StackPanel), AncestorLevel = 2 };

editor.SetBinding(editorAttribute.BindingProperty, editorBinding);
//outerPanel is the LeftEditorStack StackPanel from above
outerPanel.Children.Add(editor);
```

**Edit 2:**

After further investigation I noticed something strange. For testing my UI I use this class

```
public class Person {

    public String Firstname { get; set; }

    public String Lastname { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public String Street { get; set; }

    public Int32 ZipCode { get; set; }

    public String Location { get; set; }

}
```

All these properties are bound to textboxes. If I click on the `RadioButtons` for the `String` Properties the `ScrollViewer` resets the offset. For other properties the offset stays as it is.

Comment: You should post the code which generates dinamically your xaml

Comment: Code added to original post

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue (_ScrollViewer resets the VerticalOffset if one of the RadioButtons is clicked or if the user selects all text in one of the TextBoxes, as there is no wrapping and the text overflows the width of the TextBox_), but i did not succeed. Probably you should post as many details as for reproducing your issue

Comment: I think I've found the source for this error. When a `RadioButton` is clicked a custom event fires to compare two of the three columns and show the result in the third one. This event resets the datacontext of the third column. When I remove this event, the `RadioButtons` do not cause the `ScrollViewer` to reset the offset. I think this happens because WPF calls `Measure` and `Arrange` again...

Comment: Good, I am happy you found a solution

Comment: Nope I've found the problem, but no solution. And I've added some more information above.